# .NET PaaS on Amazon EC2

Tags: wcf, amazon-ec2, cloud, hosting

I am fairly new to the Amazon EC2.
I have devloped WCF services that can we accessed by anyone in the world.
I want to host this WCF service on cloud, due to some business requirement Azure is not my choice and I need to host it on Amazon EC2.
The services needs to be elastic and there may sudden rise and fall in accessing them(thats why cloud comes in).

I can buy an instance, configure OS and host the service there as IaaS , do we have any other option with Amazon to host it like PaaS which is possible in Azure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond elastic beanstalk (Which I'm not sure supports .NET) its not very difficult to set up your own scalable architecture within EC2. But there are a few things to be aware of that can make your job easier.

1. Your application instances should be designed around Shared Nothing architecture. These instances will be destroyed and launched at will so it should not directly store anything another instance might need.
2. If you need to use a database, or store persistant files. You can use managed options with Amazon RDS (database) and Amazon S3 (Object Storage).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, Elastic Beanstalk should suffice your needs, it does support .NET and offers PaaS like features abstracting the underlying infra quite nicely http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.html

There is also nothing stoppping you running a pure PaaS solution on top of EC2 e.g. CloudFoundry/IronFoundry to get more abstraction but this might be overkill for your solution.

As mentioned above, you need to architect and design your web service and backend data store to be cloud aware, RDS is a great solution for RDBMS but equally Dynamo DB for a NoSQL solution...

Autoscaling is built into Elastic Beanstalk so you need to use this to scale to meet your demand, also you need security groups with the port of your web service open to be internet addressable...

HTH